# Accessing Data in Cache in Business Layer

Tags: asp.net, caching, business-layer

I am trying  to develop three tier architecture.

- Data Access Layer:Will have methods for Connection String, Executing Store procedure,                Executing Select query etc. Most cases, this will return Data Set
- Business Layer:  Can Access Data Set from Data Set & provide sorting & filter data to the Web Forms.
- Presentation Layer: Will have  all web pages, user controls (if any). This Layer can access only Business Layer

This works OK for me till requirement was only limited to display records. However, when it comes to paging or sorting, each time i have to  bind fresh data, resulting in unnecessary Database Hits. To avoid this,i have stored Data Set into cache & typecasting it to Dataset objects. Is there any other alternatives for the same

Answer (score 0):

I done with binding Grid with List objects & not with Dataset. I Have initialized List  for the first time to get required Data.